# Can't get code to work in html file but will work on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am trying to use this code in my html file. It will work if I use the link http://jsfiddle.net/eqkmv/1/show/ however the javascript doesn't work when I try to View Page Source and copy/paste the code into an html file.

here is the javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#search').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

MoneyForTrip();

return false;
});

function MoneyForTrip() {
var money = parseInt(document.getElementById('moneyfortrip').value);

$('.trip-result').hide();

if (money <= 800) {
    $('.trip-less-800').show();
}

if (money > 800 && money <= 1200) {
    $('.trip-800-1200').show();
}
}
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show us your HTML file.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: My html file is just the exact copy/pasted code from the view source. As for errors, when I use an html file it won't show the destinations when I click "Show My Trips"

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Check browser console for errors, have you added a `jQuery` file to your page ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP wasn't including jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jQuery in the `<head>`

```
<script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That seemed to have done it. So do I have to include that script every time I use query code from jsfiddle?

Comment: Not all the time.. But whenever you want to use jQuery functions....

Comment: @Godin1 when setting up a jsFiddle, on the left, you can specify what version of jQuery you want to include (if any). If you check one of these options, then you need to include the script in your html